# Search an element to see if it contains a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the easiest way to search a div for a text string using jquery? I specifically want to search a div with an id and see if it contains `$(this).text()`. The purpose of this is to be able to append elements to a div but be able to prevent the same string from being written to the same div over and over.

Comment: We'll need to see some of your markup. Do your divs contain only text, or is there other HTML that needs to be navigated around? I.E., do you want to search child elements of the divs, or just the text of the div itself?

Comment: It's just <div id="search_param"></div> and text is inserted using jquery .append() and I need to check if it contains certain text using an if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I specifically want to search a div with an id and see if it contains `$(this).text()`.

I think I'd probably go with `String#indexOf`:

```
var div = $("#theId"),
    text = $(this).text();
if (div.text().indexOf(text) === -1) {
    // It doesn't have it, add it
    div.append(text); // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works perfectly. By the way, what's the point of the ===. I've seen 3 = before but I haven't ever understood the point of them.

Comment: @GavinSellers: In JavaScript, `==` will do type coercion, so you get fun things like `0 == ""` being `true`. `===` will not do type coercion, the first thing it does is check that the operands are of the same type and short-circuit (evaluating `false`) if they aren't. If they are, their values are compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector or [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method (if you need precise coincidence):

```
$("div[id]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == str;
});
```

Comment: using "==" doesn't do the same as something like "contains". you'd probably use indexOf or a regex to check (for .filter)

Comment: @ianpgall: Depends on what the OP means by "contains".